# Rails localhost custom landing page with devise

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, devise

Rails default localhost:3000 mapped to welcome_controller#index page, i want to use my custom landing page in the root. am also using devise for authentication set up.

when i give localhost:3000 devise automatically redirects to localhost:3000/users/sign_in.

how to change the root for custom page and where to place the index.html file so that can see the landing page.

Comment: Mani, try my answer and let me know if you have any question.

Answer (score 0):

You can add this to the top of your `routes.rb` file:

```
get "/" => "custom_controller#custom_action", as: :custom_root_path
```

which will give you this route:

```
custom_root_path   GET      /     custom_controller#custom_action
```

Then, you can just put the contents of your custom landing page in the corresponding view (`custom_action.html.erb` file) of the `custom_controller`'s `custom_action`.

For example, if you name your custom controller as `landing_pages_controller` and the action is `index`, then the route will be:

```
get "/" => "landing_pages#index", as: :custom_root_path
```

Then, you will have a `index` method in your `landing_pages_controller.rb` file and will have a `app/views/landing_pages/index.html.erb` file where you can put the contents of your custom landing page.

Comment: i have created welcome_controller.rb with index.html.erb file. in my application i have created some header and footer for layout in that i have used current_user, so this index.html.erb is giving error bcz its using the application layout , but i don't want to include the layout for landing page

Comment: Just create another method `landing_page` and then create a corresponding view: `landing_page.html.erb` and there put your custom landing page contents. In the case the route will be: `get "/" => "welcome_controller#landing_page`

Comment: @ManiDavid let me know if its working for you or if you have any other question.

Comment: @Rakibul, i implemented with different layout and added root "welcome#index" and its worked fine.

Comment: @ManiDavid did my answer help you solve your problem?